# serial program linux C

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I've written a small C code to program a measuring device via the serial bus. I know this device can be programmed in linux because the commands implemented worked well in gtkterm. I tried to inspire myself by the code written by the gtkterm developper team by without success. The code compiles, etc., puts out no error, but the device ignores the writes send to it. The previous posts I see on this website on this subject didn't helped me for that. Does somebody  got an idea? I got problems with my boss on that. If I don't find the problem I'll be forced to do the work in windows, which will not be easier.
The serial device works with 8N2 configuration, 1 start bit, and uses DTR/DSR hanshaking. This may be the things which causes problems. The guys of gtkterm seams to have solved the problem because it works with their program, but I didn't find the answer in their code, maybe it is a compilation issue?

I got following output:

```
init succes
configure succes
Read_port timeout
error microhmeter read
```

Thanks for your help,

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h> // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>//strtoul
#include <string.h> // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h> // UNIX standard function definitions

#include <termios.h> // POSIX terminal control definitionss
#include <fcntl.h> // File control definitions
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h> // Error number definitions

#include "microhmetre.h"

#define SELF_TEST 1

int microhmetre_fd = -1;
struct termios tio_save;

int microhmetre_Init(void)
{
    microhmeter_close();
    char* portName = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
    int err;
    /** open serial ports**/
    microhmetre_fd = open(portName, O_RDWR  | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if(microhmetre_fd==-1) {
        err = errno;
        printf("openPort ERROR %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }
    /**Configuring serial port transmission type**/
    struct termios newtio;

    if(!isatty(microhmetre_fd)) {
        printf("port %d is not a tty\n", microhmetre_fd);
        close(microhmetre_fd);
        microhmetre_fd = -1;
        return 1;
    }

    //bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio)); // clear struct for new port settings
    tcgetattr(microhmetre_fd, &newtio);
    memcpy(&tio_save, &newtio, sizeof(struct termios));

    //setting c_cflags
    newtio.c_cflag = B9600;//baud rate
    newtio.c_cflag |= CS8;//set 8 bits

    newtio.c_cflag |= CSTOPB;//|= CSTOPB; 2 stop bits &=~CSTOPB; 1 stop bit
    newtio.c_cflag |= (CREAD | CLOCAL); //enable receiver

    //l_flags
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;

    //i_flags
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | IGNBRK;

    //o_flags
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;

    //other flags
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 1; //Inter-char timer 1s read timeout

    //apply settings

    if(tcsetattr(microhmetre_fd, TCSANOW, &newtio)<0) {
        printf("Unable to apply given port settings\n");
        close(microhmetre_fd);
        microhmetre_fd = -1;
        return 1;
    }
    tcflush(microhmetre_fd, TCOFLUSH);
    tcflush(microhmetre_fd, TCIFLUSH);

    return 0;
}

void microhmeter_close(void){
    if( microhmetre_fd != -1){
        tcsetattr(microhmetre_fd, TCSANOW, &tio_save);
        tcflush(microhmetre_fd, TCOFLUSH);
        tcflush(microhmetre_fd, TCIFLUSH);
        close(microhmetre_fd);
        microhmetre_fd = -1;
    }
}

int microhmeter_write(char * buf, int length)
{
    if (microhmetre_fd == -1) return 1;
    if (length = 0) return 0;
    int res, err;

    /*Write data*/
    res = write(microhmetre_fd, buf, length);
    if( res < 0){
        err = errno;
        printf("write failed: error %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (res != length){
        printf("write not completed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        tcdrain(microhmetre_fd);//attendre la fin de l'envoie.
    }

    return 0;
}


int microhmeter_configure(void)
{
    char * remote = "SYST:REM\n";

    if(microhmeter_write(remote, 9)){
        printf("configure remote failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    sleep(1);
    char * trig_bus = "TRIG:SOURCE BUS\n";
    if(microhmeter_write(trig_bus, 16)){
        printf("configure trig bus failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    sleep(1);
    return 0;

}

int microhmeter_read(int recvBytes, char * buf)
{
    unsigned long time;
    unsigned long mesure;
    int res;
    //select
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(microhmetre_fd, &rfds);
    //Timeout 500ms
    tv.tv_sec = 3;
    tv.tv_usec = 500000;

    while(retval == 0) {
        retval = select(microhmetre_fd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if(retval == -1) {
            printf("Select Error in read port\n");
            return 1;
        } else if (retval) {
            res = read(microhmetre_fd, buf, recvBytes);
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Read_port timeout\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(res==15){
        buf[res] = 0;
        //TODO enregistrer et renvoyer la mesure
    } else {
        printf("error in read microhmeter\n");
        return 1; //something is wrong
    }

    return 0;

}

int microhmeter_getMes(long double* mes)
{
    char * mes_cmd = "MEAS:FRES?\n";
    if(microhmeter_write(mes_cmd, 11)){
        printf("error microhmeter write\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[16];
    if(microhmeter_read(16, buf)){
        printf("error microhmeter read\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char ** res;
    *mes = strtold(buf, res);
    return 0;
}
#if SELF_TEST
int main(void){

    long double mes;
    if(microhmetre_Init()) {
        printf("error init\n");
        return 1;
    } else printf("init succes\n");

    if(microhmeter_configure()) {
        microhmeter_close();
        return 1;
    }
    else printf("configure succes\n");

    if(microhmeter_getMes(&mes)) {
        microhmeter_close();
        return 1;
    }
    else printf("mesure succès\n");

    printf("mes = %Lf", mes);

    microhmeter_close();
    return 0;

}
#endif // SELF_TEST
```

The result of sudo strace -e trace=write ./microhmeter

```
write(1, "init succes\n", 12init succes
)           = 12
write(3, "", 0)                         = 0
write(3, "", 0)                         = 0
write(1, "configure succes\n", 17configure succes
)      = 17
write(3, "", 0)                         = 0
write(1, "Read_port timeout\n", 18Read_port timeout
)     = 18
write(1, "error microhmeter read\n", 23error microhmeter read
) = 23
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: So you have a bug. Use debugger.

Comment: Or rather, when debugging RS-232, attach a listener to the bus and see what's actually there. If you have a PC with multiple serial ports, this can be easily achieved by only connecting rx and ground to a second port, view the data in a terminal. Alternatively, poor man's serial listener: use a scope and decode the RS-232 data manually. Yuck.

Comment: @Lundin I remember using something called `com0com` in windows... Pretty sure something like this can be found for Linux. But it can affect timing.

Comment: Start simple, no handshaking, send a few characters to a terminal. Ditto for receive, type a few at the terminal.

Comment: Side note: your select read loop does not grant to read 15 chars.

Comment: on linux (and many other OSs), when calling `select()` with a timeout, that `timeout` parameter must be reset before every calll, because `select()` decrements the value(s) in the timeout.

Comment: the posted code seems to be missing the `c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;` statement

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. ''magic' numbers are those with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  some of the 'magic' numbers are: 9, 11, 16.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: how do you know that `/dev/ttyUSB0` is the desired port for your peripheral?  Have you tried talking to it using `putty` or similar utility?

Comment: the posted code assumes a problem occurred if the number of bytes read is not 15 (another 'magic' number that needs to be properly defined) however, `select()` returns as soon as ANY characters are available to read.  I.E. if the total number of characters read is > 0 and <15 then need to loop back to the `select()`, until all characters read or a timeout occurs.  Remember, in linux, need to reset the timeout variable just before each call to `select()`.   Also, this line: `if(res==15)` is incorrect, it should be: `if(res==recvBytes)`